# Import/export localData to/from a user profile of Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: local-storage, chromium

Is it safe to just copy/paste a specific sqlite file with .localstorage extension in folder of "User Data\Default\Local Storage\" from one profile to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have some doubt about passwords. You can read here the problem (still open): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29013